# Best way to get values from multiple complex child components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a parent component that has base data called script, which has multiple sequences and each sequence is composed of multiple items (inputs, dropdown, ... ).

Now I need the updated data in parent since I want to put a save button that is going to save all forms with one click.

It looks something like this:

### [image: example]

I tried two ways of handling this:

- That each child had an onChange property
  in which parent sets the state with the new data. But the problem
  here is, that since this is quite a complex form, it re-renders
  everything each time, so there was a noticeable delay when typing in
  inputs.
- The "bad" of just changing the props object in a child,
  which is fast, but I know it is a bad practice.

What is the best way of handling forms on a scale like this? Should it be set up differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a question I've spent some time struggling with myself. There are multiple ways to maintain child state at a higher level; however, I've found that in your particular situation it is often best to use Redux.

To be clear, I generally avoid Redux at all costs (in favor of React's context), but Redux gives you the ability to subscribe to a particular piece of state in your child components. Listening to one piece of state in a child component will prevent your parent and sibling components from updating when you only need a single child to update. This ends up being far more efficient when handling multiple forms at one time.

For example, the following component will only listen to state updates that affect its own state. These updates will bypass the forms parent and sibling components:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from 'redux/actions';
// Custom component
import { InputField } from 'shared';

const FormOne = ({ me, actions }) => (
  <form>
    <InputField
      inputId="f1f1"
      label="field one"
      value={me.fieldOne}
      onChange={(e) => actions.setFormOneFieldOne(e.target.value)}
    />
    <InputField
      inputId="f1f2"
      label="field two"
      value={me.fieldTwo}
      onChange={(e) => actions.setFormOneFieldTwo(e.target.value)}
    />
    <InputField
      inputId="f1f3"
      label="field three"
      value={me.fieldThree}
      onChange={(e) => actions.setFormOneFieldThree(e.target.value)}
    />
  </form>
);

export default connect(state => ({ me: state.formOne }), actions)(FormOne);
```

In the above example `FormOne` is only listening for its own state updates; whereas, similar logic utilizing context instead of Redux will cause the entire component tree that the context provider is wrapping to update (including parent and sibling components):

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
// Custom component
import { InputField } from 'shared';
// Custom context - below component must be wrapped with the provider
import { FormContext } from 'context';


const FormTwo = () => {
  const context = useContext(FormContext);

  return(
    <form>
      <InputField
        inputId="f2f1"
        label="field one"
        value={context.state.formTwo.fieldOne}
        onChange={(e) => context.setFormTwoFieldOne(e.target.value)}
      />
      <InputField
        inputId="f2f2"
        label="field two"
        value={context.state.formTwo.fieldTwo}
        onChange={(e) => context.setFormTwoFieldTwo(e.target.value)}
      />
      <InputField
        inputId="f2f3"
        label="field three"
        value={context.state.formTwo.fieldThree}
        onChange={(e) => context.setFormTwoFieldThree(e.target.value)}
      />
    </form>
  );
};

export default FormTwo;
```

There are some improvements that can be made to both of the above components, but they are meant to serve as an example for how to connect child components to an elevated state. It is also possible to connect to a single parent component using `props`, but that is the least efficient option possible, and will clutter up your architecture.

**Key takeaway:** Use Redux for your use case. It's the most efficient option if it is implemented correctly.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to avoid Redux for simplicity, but I guess that will get hard eventually. Do you think this could be solved efficiently with PureComponent or would redux still be better?

Comment: `React.PureComponent` or `React.memo` are good options in some situations, but I would avoid them in yours for two reasons: 1.  In general hooks is the way forward with React, so `React.PureComponent` restricts your architecture. 2. Your use case is fairly complex, and as it scales you'll need to elevate your state to keep a clean architecture. The two main options for that are Redux and context. In this situation Redux will be more performant.

Comment: To be clear here, you could still use `React.memo` to implement functional components even if you decided to use Redux. It probably won't add much of a performance boost for you though if everything is setup correctly.

Comment: I did some thinking and redux is the way to go. I should only use redux state for complex things and still use normal state when using simple components, right?

Comment: The only issue I have with this is that using Redux will take a lot of time to implement in the current time when context will be way quicker. Do you think the performance difference is significant that I should use Redux?

Comment: I think it is worth your time to design your architecture in a clean, efficient, and performative manner. My personal opinion is that you should always do what makes sense. For instance, it is possible (and in my mind recommended) to use Redux, context, and local state all in the same application if there is a reason. For instance, your example is a reason to add Redux, but there may also be a section of your component tree that makes more sense with context. There's no reason not to have both in the same application. There is also always a reason to have local state in some components.

Comment: Just to be clear, React is moving away from Class components, right? It's best to use function components with hooks moving forward? Or are there any use cases where classes are still prefered?

Comment: Yes, functional components and hooks are preferred moving forward. There are still a couple of use cases for class components, but they are very rare. You’ll know if and when you come across one.

Answer (score 1):

Lifting state up is indeed the correct way of doing this. To optimize child sections you can use

> - PureComponent ==>  https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent
> - AKA Memoized Component ==> https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo

React.memo is a higher order component. It’s similar to React.PureComponent but for function components instead of classes.

Also if you are within the hooks universe checkout

> - useCallback : https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback
> - useMemo : https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo

If you are using Redux by any chance remember to look at

> - reselect : https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect

Comment: Thanks, what is the difference between PureComponent and Memoized Component, they do basically the same, is the performance the same as well? Or should I use one over the other?

Comment: React.memo is a higher order component. It’s similar to React.PureComponent but for function components instead of classes.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap all the forms in a component that will only deal with saving all the forms data and running the "save all" function:

the wrapper component should have a state the includes all the forms data, it should probably look something like this:

```
class Wrapper Component extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      formsData: {},
    };
  }
}
```

formsData should probably be structured pretty much like that:
{ 0: { title:"text", type:"video", etc:"etc" },
  1: { title:"text", type:"video", etc:"etc" }}
the keys (0,1, etc..) represents the form id, and can be set to any unique modifier each for has.

then make the wrapper component handle the onChange for every individual form -> every change on each individual form should uplift the new state (new updated data) and update the formsData state obj accordingly:

```
const onChange(formData) {
   const formattedData = {[formData.id]: {...formData}}
   this.setState({formsData: {...formsData, ...formattedData}})
}
```

* This is just an example of a case where in each change in each form you uplift the entire data object, you can do it in many ways

Than, the save all button should also be handled in the wrapper component, and uplift all the data you stored with it to the relevant function in a parent component / handle it itself.

Good luck!